# Rspec controller can't call the action of real controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

i'm using `rails 4.1.1` and `rspec 3.0.3`.

here is the rspec code.

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe MembersController, type: :controller do

  describe 'GET index' do

    it 'should be success' do
      puts "11111"
      get :index
      puts "33333"
      expect(response).to render_template :index
    end

  end

end
```

and `:index` action of controller is,

```
def index
    puts "22222"
    @members = Member.order('mem_id DESC').paginate(page: params[:page]||1, per_page: params[:per_page]||30)
end
```

==============================

and i did 'rake spec', i exepcted the console to print like this.

```
11111
22222
33333
```

but the result is,

```
11111
33333
```

and it makes an error message like this.

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template :index
       expecting <"index"> but rendering with <[]>
```

what's wrong with my rspec?

----------------------------------- **UPDATE QUESTION** ------------------------------

this is the `spec/rails_helper.rb` (all comments are removed)

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

Comment: `puts "22222"` never print to console look into `log/test.log`. And show `spec_helper.rb` please.

Comment: `spec_helper.rb` has nothing but `RSpec.configure do |config| end` block. but `spec/rails_helper.rb` has some configuration, can i show you this?

Comment: Also `expect(response).to render_template :index` should be before `get :index`.

Comment: add `config.render_views` to `spec_helper.rb`.